# Change post default audience from the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, session, facebook-ios-sdk, audience

My iOS app starts with "Friends" as default audience. I would like to let the user change the default audience to, for example, "Everyone" from inside the iOS App.

I have tried clearing the tokens, and reopening the session with the new audience, and also reauthorising an existent and valid session with the new audience. Both did not work.

What it's the right way to change the default audience from the iOS SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can deauthorize the app and re-request for publish permissions for user to see the extended permission dialog.

Comment: +1, or tell the user to go to their privacy settings and choose a new 'maximum visibility' for posts made by the app

Comment: I will try that. Is there any way to change that "per-post" directly from the FBRequest object?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need make something like this -

```
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        loginManager.defaultAudience = FBSDKDefaultAudienceEveryone;
```